# Passing a function with arguments as an argument and retrieving data

Tags: javascript, function

Good Morning everyone,

So I have a rather confusing question so I will try to be as clear as possible and keep it just as concise.

Assume that I have a function `basicFunction`. `basicFunction` has two arguments of `funcWithParams` and `callback`.

```
basicFunction(funcWithParams, callback){
    .
    .
    .
    // do stuff here
}
```

`funcwIthParams` is exactly what it says, a function either with or with out arguments, argument `callback` is a function that triggers when the initial part of `basicFunction` is completed.

With all that being said above, here is my question. Is it possible when passing a function with parameter to grab the function name itself, and each individual argument that was passed with it, and the value of each passed argument? I know for sure you can get a function name as a string, but I'm not exactly sure about the arguments and the values for each.

I have been researching this like crazy for the last three days, and I'm sure there is a way, but I have yet to find an answer.

**Example**

```
function basicFunction(funcWithParams, callback){
     // create a loop to go through and log each of the parameters in the first argument's function

}

function somethingElse(param1, param2, param3){

}

function callbackFunction(){
   alert("I did stuff");
}

basicFunction(somethingElse(param1, param2, param3), callbackFunction);
```

Comment: Just to get some clarity, you are asking if you can pass a function, `funcWithParams`, into `basicFunction` as an argument which itself has parameters pre-populated but not yet called?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by _"Is it possible to actually pass a function with parameters"_ - could you clarify that, possibly with an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: Is funcWithParams basically a pointer to a function?

Comment: Are you by any chance doing `basicFunction(func(a, b, c), callback)`? If not, how are you passing in a function with parameters?

Comment: typically when you pass a function, it's un-executed at that time, so there are no arguments to it. you can divine the names of said function's formal parameters, but those are just words, not meaningful values.

Comment: I have provided edits and yes @Blender you are correct

Comment: @MarkHill: `basicFunction` **calls** `funcWithParams` at some point, right? E.g., via `funcWithParams();` somewhere in `basicFunction`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes this is correct

Comment: @MarkHill: `foo(1, 2, 3)` executes `foo` *immediately* with arguments `1, 2, 3`. You're not passing in the function itself, you're passing in the *return value* of the function call.

Comment: @Blender is it possible to explain more thoroughly as an answer?

Comment: @MarkHill: I'm not really sure what else to explain. `f(1)` calls the function `f` with the argument `1`. When you write `f(1, 2, 3)`, you call the function immediately, there isn't some intermediate object that holds the function `f` bound with the arguments `1, 2, 3` (that's what `f.bind(null, 1, 2, 3)` does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for something usually called *partial application* or *currying* (after the mathematician Haskell Curry).

JavaScript doesn't have pure currying (built in; it's easy to add), but does have `Function#bind`, which lets you create a function based on another function that, when called, will call the original function with a specific `this` value and with any arguments you give. If you don't care about `this`, just use `null`. As that's clear as mud, let's have an example:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log(a + ", " + b);
}
foo(1, 2); // "1, 2"

// Create curried version
var bar = foo.bind(null, 100);

// Call curried version
bar(200);  // "100, 200"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

There, we "curried" the value 100 for the argument `a` when creating `bar` from `foo`.

So in your example, you'd do this:

```
basicFunction(somethingElse.bind(null, param1, param2, param3), callbackFunction);
```

---

Re your comment:

> This is almost what I'm trying to do, but instead what I'm looking at is something like `bar(foo(1,2), 100);`, and from this getting the results of "foo" as a string, and the values of 1 and 2.

If you do `bar(foo(1,2),100)`, `foo` gets **called** with the arguments `1` and `2`, and then its return value is passed into `bar` along with `100`. By the time `bar` is called, there is no information passed to it that in any way refers back to `foo`, `1`, or `2`. Exactly the way `x = foo(1, 2)` sets the return value of `foo` on `x`, again without anything continuing to refer back to `foo` (or `1` or `2`) from `x`.

If you want access to the args, then the only thing that comes to mind is to pass an object with the function and its arguments, like this:

```
bar({f: foo, args: [1, 2]}, 100);
```

Then, in `bar`:

```
function bar(finfo, additionalArg) {
    console.log(finfo.f.name);    // "foo", probably, see caveats
    console.log(finfo.args[0]);   // 1
    console.log(finfo.args[1]);   // 2

    // calling it
    finfo.f.apply(null, finfo.args);
}
```

`Function#apply` calls the function you call it on, using the first argument you give it as the `this` value for the call, and then using the arguments you give it as an array as the individual arguments to pass the function.

**Live Example**:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("foo called with " + a + " and " + b);
}

function bar(finfo, additionalArg) {
  console.log(finfo.f.name);  // "foo", probably, see caveats
  console.log(finfo.args[0]); // 1
  console.log(finfo.args[1]); // 2

  // calling it
  snippet.log("bar calling finfo.f via apply");
  finfo.f.apply(null, finfo.args);
}

snippet.log("Calling bar");
bar({f: foo, args: [1, 2]}, 100);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Caveats:

1. `Function#name` was commonly provided by browsers, but wasn't part of the spec until June of this year when ECMAScript 6th Edition (ES6) came out. So you may find the odd browser that doesn't support it. If so, you may have to do the horrible `toString` thing to figure out the function's name.
2. Not all functions have names. ES6 gives many formerly-anonymous functions names, but it's still possible to create anonymous functions, and not all browsers will support the various ways ES6 infers function names (for instance, from expressions like `var f = function() { };`).

The only **truly guaranteed** way to provide a *name* for `foo` is to do it manually when creating the function:

```
function foo() {
//...
}
foo.name = "foo";
```

Soon that won't be true, but it is in today's world.

Comment: This is almost what I'm trying to do, but instead what I'm looking at is something like `bar(foo(1,2), 100);`, and from this getting the results of "foo" as a string, and the values of 1 and 2.

Comment: @MarkHill: I've updated the answer. Doesn't sound like you want `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with an instance of a class, you may need to worry about context. In this case, it makes sense to bind. For instance:

```
function Sum() {
  this._total = 0;
  this.addTen = this.add.bind(this, 10);
}

Sum.prototype.add = function(amount) {
  this._total += amount;
  return this;
};

Sum.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '' + this._total;
};

var sum = new Sum();
sum.addTen().addTen();
console.info(sum);
// 20
```

However, outside of an instance, there is usually no need for context and the more appropriate form of currying may be to create a factory function, like so:

```
function createAdder(amount1) {
  return function AddTo(amount2) {
    return amount1 + amount2;
  };
}

var addTenTo = createAdder(10);
var fifty = addTenTo(40);

console.info(fifty);
// 50
```

This usually comes down to implementation details and preference. There are good uses and arguments for both methods.

Comment: Why is bind not appropriate outside of an instance?

Comment: @Blender: Can't speak for rrowland, but *one* problem with using bind for currying is that it interferes with `this` by forcing you to choose what `this` is at the time you bind, instead of when you call the function. That's why I have a `Function#curry` I add to `Function.prototype` that passes through the `this` unchanged. One can also infer from rrowland's example that he's basically saying that it's better to create a *specific* curry-ier rather than just using a generic one. `createAdder` creates a specific kind of curried function.

Comment: @Blender: As TJ mentioned, binding forces the developer to choose the context on bind rather than on call. There is a good amount of personal opinion here, as well. The latter form of currying is a more common approach in functional programming across languages (Bind is very unique to JS).

Comment: I feel like this came across too strongly as "binding without a context is always wrong" which wasn't the intention. I mainly wanted to point out there's an alternative way to curry. I'll update my answer to reflect that.